# Transform long timestamp to something shorter?

Tags: vba

I have a variable **startDate** = "24/Apr/20 3:51 AM", I also have another variable **sCreateDate** = "2020-04-03T15:17:34.000-0400".

1. I would like variable sCreateDate to look like Variable startDate
2. Compare both variables and identify if Variable sCreateDate is greater than Variable startDate.

Here is the code that I am using but it does not work:

```
Format(sCreateDate, "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM")
```

Comment: In order to compare them in that way, you would have to put them both into date variables, not string variables. The only way you can compare String variables is just to see if they are exactly equal.

Comment: ^ And `Format` returns a `Variant/String` so you wouldn't use that.

Comment: @braX - put them into date variable as in CDATE?

Comment: Yeah, `CDate` should work, just make sure that the variable you store what `CDate` returns is a `Date` variable type and not a string, as VBA will convert what CDate returns to a string automatically if it needs to.

Comment: `CDate` won't work on "2020-04-03T15:17:34.000-0400" though.

Comment: I tried, but in vain. So, the string variable [sCreateDate] gets its value from a JSON object like so - sCreateDate = JSONObj("issues")(iCounter)("fields")("created"). And, I did this next - Debug.Print CDate(sCreateDate) and it spits a "Type Mismatch" error. The JSON object is Variant/String if it matters

Comment: @Applecore - So it seems.

Comment: You can use `Format` to get it into a string that `CDate` can understand first then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably going to have to do some Date/Time building. Here is some VBA to get you going:

```
Function fDateConvert(strDate As String) As Date
    fDateConvert = DateSerial(Left(strDate, 4), Mid(strDate, 6, 2), Mid(strDate, 9, 2)) + TimeSerial(Mid(strDate, 12, 2), Mid(strDate, 15, 2), 0)
End Function
```

We start by using `DateSerial` to create the date part, and take the left 4 characters to get the year, the sixth and seventh characters to get the month, and then the ninth and tenth to get the day.

Next we build the time part using `TimeSerial` by extracting the hours and minutes parts from the original string, and set the seconds to be 0.

And finally these two parts get added together to give the full date time.

Regards,

Comment: It's breathing but I have a couple of observations. Your function above is spitting this  4/3/2020 3:17:34 PM, but can I make it spit this instead 04/03/2020 3:17?

Comment: I've modified the code to be a function now, accepting the string and returning the date/time extracted. I've set the seconds to be 0 as needed. When I run this with the given input, I get "04/03/2020 15:17:00", If it needs to appear differently to the user then you can use a Date/Time format on it.